# JPA OneToMany Relationship without a Join Table

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Table Structure, which models how a single Item can have many Translations in different languages.

```
ITEM
| ID | NAME | TRA_ID |
Primary Key: ID
Foreign Key: TRA_ID -> TRA_TRANSLATION.ID
Note TRA_ID can be set to null

TRANSLATION
| ID | LANGUAGE | TEXT |
Primary Key: ID+LANGUAGE
```

I had hoped I could represent this using the following in JPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
class Item(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    val id: String,

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    val name: String,

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(
        table = "TRANSLATION",
        name = "TRA_ID",
        referencedColumnName = "ID"
    )
    val translations: List<Translation> = emptyList()
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSLATION")
class Translation(

    @EmbeddedId
    val key: ID,

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    val text: String
) {

    @Embeddable
    data class ID(

        @Column(name = "ID")
        val id: String,

        @Column(name = "LANGUAGE")
        val language: String,

    ) : Serializable
}
```

However when I do a simple operation e.g. jpa repository `findAll()` I get the following exception: `NotYetImplementedException: Collections having FK in secondary table`

Is this possible? I'm trying to avoid introducing a Join Table as it seems over kill to introduce an extra table for the sake of storing the data model above.

Comment: Given your DB model, it looks like 1 `Item` can be linked to 0 or 1 `Translation`, `Item *..? Translation`. Shouldn't `Item` hold `Translation translation` instead of `List<Translation> translations`, with a `@ManyToOne` annotation instead? The reverse `@OneToMany` mapping should be on the `Translation` class instead if needed (but it doesn't look like it would make much sense to have it in your case).

Comment: Its technically a One to 0/Many relationship i.e One Item can have 0 or many Translations (one per language)

Comment: On the Translation Table there is a composite key (which the TRANSLATION.ID is one component of). So one ITEM.TRA_ID maps to 0 or more Translation rows

Comment: Lets say for example we have one row in the Item Table: "Telephone". This could have multiple rows in the Translation Table e.g. [id=123,language=EN,text=Telephone], [id=123,language=ES,text=Telefono]. Given the Translation IDs are the same for both (which is how my data model works) but they have a different Language I have represented this via a composite key in the Translation table.

Comment: Ah, I see, my bad, thanks for those details (might be worth putting them in the question directly for future readers). Not sure how to express this with JPA.

Comment: I think representing it as a ManyToMany with JoinColumn annotations seems to help

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I ended up with the below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
class Item(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    val id: String,

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    val name: String,

    // Note, not mapping via JPA here as it doesnt seem possible
    @Column(name = "TRA_ID")
    val translationId: String? = null
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSLATION")
class Translation(

    @EmbeddedId
    val key: ID,

    @Column(name = "TEXT")
    val text: String
) {

    @Embeddable
    data class ID(

        @Column(name = "ID")
        val id: String,

        @Column(name = "LANGUAGE")
        val language: String,

    ) : Serializable
}
```

And then using Entity Manager with multiple returns to query

```
val result: Map<Item, List<Translation>> = em.createQuery(
        """
        SELECT itm, tra FROM Item itm
        LEFT JOIN FETCH Translation tra ON itm.translationId = tra.key.id
    """
).resultList
        .let { it as List<Array<Any>> }
        .groupBy({ it[0] as Item }, { it[1] as Translation })
```